Store and retrieve encrypted binary data with GridDB using Python's cryptography library
I'm working with a GridDB setup and want to future-proof it against quantum computing threats by implementing post-quantum encryption. I've started by testing a basic integration using encrypted data storage with cryptography library and GridDB. Here’s my code:
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import griddb_python as griddb

# Generate encryption key
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)

# Sample data encryption
data = "Quantum Safe Data"
encrypted_data = cipher_suite.encrypt(data.encode())

# Initialize GridDB connection
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
try:
    gridstore = factory.get_store(
        host="localhost", port=10001, cluster_name="defaultCluster",
        username="admin", password="admin"
    )
    container_name = "quantum_test"
    conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo(
        name=container_name,
        column_info_list=[["id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                          ["data", griddb.Type.STRING]],
        type=griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, row_key=True)
    
    container = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)
    container.set_auto_commit(False)

    # Storing encrypted data
    row = [1, encrypted_data]
    container.put_row(row)
    container.commit()

    # Retrieve and decrypt data
    query = container.query("select *")
    rs = query.fetch()
    while rs.has_next():
        row = rs.next()
        decrypted_data = cipher_suite.decrypt(row[1]).decode()
        print("Decrypted Data:", decrypted_data)

except griddb.GSException as e:
    print("GridDB Error:", e)

Issue:
When running the above code, I encounter the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "griddb_encryption_test.py", line 32, in <module>
    decrypted_data = cipher_suite.decrypt(row[1]).decode()
  File "/path/to/python/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 117, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "/path/to/python/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 166, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise TypeError("token must be bytes")
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str

How should encrypted binary data be handled in GridDB containers? Should I be converting data differently for storage/retrieval to prevent these type issues?

This has nothing to do with post-quantum crypto. The issue is that you've specified that the data column is a string, but Fernet.encrypt() returns a bytes object containing base64-encoded data, and that's what you attempt to store in the DB. Yet when you retrieve it from the DB, it's magically a string. I guess GridDB 'converts' the bytes object to a string somehow.
Rather than rely on some automatic conversion, just convert it yourself. The value returned from encrypt is a bytes object containing base64 encoded data. That means it's ASCII, which is decoded correctly when specifying UTF8 decoding, which is the default for python, so TLDR just supply the UTF8-decoded string when inserting. When retrieving, UTF8-encode the string back to bytes before decrypting, e.g.
# ...
# Storing encrypted data
    row = [1, encrypted_data.decode()]
# ...

and then later
# ...
row = rs.next()
decrypted_data = cipher_suite.decrypt(row[1].encode()).decode()
# ...

